# elastic4s + elasticsearch Geodistance query with two documents at the same location

Tags: scala, search, elasticsearch, geospatial, elastic4s

I'm using Elasticsearch to index Geographic data and I have two points indexed;

```
{
  _index: "shops",
  _type: "coffee",
  _id: "2",
  _version: 73,
  found: true,
  _source: {
  location: {
    lat: 50,
    lon: 50
  },
  name: "some random cafe"
  }
}
```

And then I have another point;

```
{
  _index: "shops",
  _type: "coffee",
  _id: "3",
  _version: 73,
  found: true,
  _source: {
  location: {
    lat: 50,
    lon: 50
  },
  name: "another random cafe"
  }
}
```

The mapping is correct

```
{
  shops: {
    mappings: {
      coffee: {
        dynamic: "true",
        numeric_detection: true,
        properties: {
          location: {
            type: "geo_point",
            lat_lon: true,
            geohash: true
          },
          name: {
            type: "string",
            format: "dateOptionalTime"
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

I'm then querying for all points within 500km within (49.9999, 49.9999), which I'm sure is within the distance;

```
val lat: Double = 50
val lat: Double = 49.9999
val dist: String = "500km"
client execute {
      search in “shops" -> “coffee" filter {
        and (
          geoDistance("location") point(lat, lon) distance dist,
          or(modelIdTerms:_*)
        )
      } sourceInclude(“name")
    } await
```

Gives me only 1 hit. Exactly the same query via `curl` gives me two hits. Is this possibly a bug with Elastic4s?